# Trying to do a checksum on a file I have to install (16.04)

Tags: bios

First of all I'm a tenderfoot to this OS.  I just installed the OS and one of the first things I'm trying to do is update the BIOS on my MB.  The the BIOS is located here, http://global.shuttle.com/main/productsDownload?productId=1383
As you can see, there's a checksum for this file.  The thing is I don't have a clue how to check for this checksum after I download it.  I assumed that I could right click the file after the download, but it wasn't that easy.

After I do manage to check the checksum.  I'm going to need help installing it.  I'm not really sure Ubuntu will be able to install it or not.  I'm working to install the latest file on the page posted.

For reference I install my OS from a CD on a mag that Ubuntu released.  It's a 64 bit 16.04 install.